# BAD GLOBAL OR LOCAL REF PASSED TO JNI

Tags: java-native-interface

I am kind of new to JNI topic.I created a hash table in my java code and tried to access it in the c native code.I am getting an FATAL ERROR : BAD GLOBAL OR LOCAL REF PASSED TO JNI.It would helpful if someone figure out the problem and explain the reason.My native code is as follows

```c
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloWorld.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{

   jclass mainclass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
   jmethodID createHashid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, mainclass, 
  "createHash", "()Ljava/util/Hashtable;");
   jobject  hashtable = (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env, mainclass, 
   createHashid);
   jclass hashtableClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, hashtable);

  jmethodID getkeyset = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, hashtableClass, "keySet", "
  ()Ljava/util/Set;");
  jmethodID getvalue = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, hashtableClass, "get", "
  (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
  jobject keyset = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, hashtable, getkeyset);

  jclass setclass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java.util.Set");


  jmethodID toarrayid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, setclass, "toArray", "()Ljava/lang/Object;"); //MY CODE CRASHES AT THIS LINE 


  jobjectArray keyarray = (jobjectArray)((*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, 
  keyset, toarrayid));`enter code here`
  jint len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, keyarray);

  for (jint i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
     jstring key = (jstring)((*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, keyarray, 
     i));
     jstring value = (jstring)((*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, hashtable, 
     getvalue, key));
     const char *keystr = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, key, NULL);
     const char *valuestr = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, value, NULL);
     printf("%s %s\n", keystr, valuestr);
  } 
}
```

Comment: `FindClass(env, "java.util.Set")`  <-- surely that ought to be `FindClass(env, "java/util/Set")` ?

Comment: thank for the response ,, but whats the probable mistake ,, why is my findclass not returning the correct reference ??

Comment: yes your right ,, the findclass is returning null ,, but cannot figure out the mistake

Comment: actually it is throwing a NoClassDefFound error !!

Comment: Read my first comment again. I mentioned what change you should make.

Comment: Thanks a lot ..it worked..